# Why Windows 10 firewall turns itself on?

Tags: windows-10, firewall

I'm running into the issue disabling Windows 10 Firewall -- it gets disabled, but after several seconds something enables it back. There were no programs installed or configuration changes mage when this started to happen.

[Here is a Screencast demonstrating the issue](http://screencast.com/t/sSJoMSdWp).

When I shutdown Firewall in a hard way via stopping the underlying service it gets disabled, however, Cortana stops working ... But that's yet another story.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1. Event Log**

After turning off I see two event log entries made.

```
A Windows Firewall setting in the Public profile has changed.
New Setting:
    Type:   Enable Windows Firewall
    Value:  No
    Modifying User: EUGENE-PC\nrj
    Modifying Application:  C:\Windows\System32\dllhost.exe
```

And the second after 13 seconds -- something reset the configuration to default...

```
Windows Firewall has been reset to its default configuration.

    ModifyingUser:  SYSTEM
    ModifyingApplication:   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\netsh.exe
```

**UPDATE 2. Auditing process tracking results**

After enabling audit process tracking here is the trail that the automatic firewall enabling leaves.

```
A new process has been created.

Creator Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       EUGENE-PC$
    Account Domain:     NGROUP
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Target Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Process Information:
    New Process ID:     0x1ae4
    New Process Name:   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\netsh.exe
    Token Elevation Type:   %%1936
    Mandatory Label:        Mandatory Label\System Mandatory Level
    Creator Process ID: 0x798
    Creator Process Name:   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe
    Process Command Line:
```

**UPDATE 3. SOLUTION!**

Using the Scott Chamberlain's advice I've finally figured out execution initiation path and found the culprit!

Here is Event log entries that allowed to figure this out.

```
A new process has been created.

Creator Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       EUGENE-PC$
    Account Domain:     NGROUP
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Target Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Process Information:
    New Process ID:     **0x1950**
    New Process Name:   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe
    Token Elevation Type:   %%1936
    Mandatory Label:        Mandatory Label\System Mandatory Level
    Creator Process ID: 0xca0
    Creator Process Name:   **C:\Program Files (x86)\TunnelBear\TBear.Maintenance.exe**
    Process Command Line:
```

Then entry for netsh run goes and it starts by Process with ID **0x1950**!

```
Process Information:
    New Process ID:     0x21b4
    New Process Name:   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\netsh.exe
    Token Elevation Type:   %%1936
    Mandatory Label:        Mandatory Label\System Mandatory Level
    Creator Process ID: 0x1950
    Creator Process Name:   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe
    Process Command Line:
```

Here is our "hero" that made me go mad: https://www.tunnelbear.com/.

[image: hero]

Comment: Are you on a domain? And do you have any 3rd party anti-virus software installed?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, no antivirus, even tried turn off Windows Defender -- with no difference. I'm in a working group, no domain, or domain policies applied.

Comment: If you're not on a domain, then what's "NGROUP"?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, it's "workgroup" with 2 my computers inside.

Comment: @Psycogeek, the thing is that I've marked Scott Chamberlain's advice as solution, because it is his advise - I just did last step myself.

Comment: Instead of updating the post with the answer, try submitting an answer to the question. That way other people can find the answer easier (Since this is a Q&A site, not an AinQ site (:  )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really a solution, but this may help you figure out what is causing it.

Check your event log by running the "Event Viewer" app. Go to [`Applications and Services logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv7zV.png) and view the [Firewall log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S97YD.png).

That log should log a event whenever the firewall is enabled or disabled with a event similar to

```
A Windows Firewall setting in the Public profile has changed.
New Setting:
    Type:   Enable Windows Firewall
    Value:  Yes
    Modifying User: MyMachine\srchamberlain
    Modifying Application:  C:\Windows\System32\dllhost.exe
```

You can check the `Modifying Application` property to see which app initiated the firewall change.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

So it appears something is running `netsh` on a semi-regular basis. I would check `Applications and Services logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> TaskScheduler -> Operational` in the event viewer to see if it is a scheduled task doing it.

If that does not show it being run run `secpol.msc` and and enable [Audit process tracking](https://superuser.com/questions/603226/does-windows-log-programs-that-have-been-run-called) to see who started `netsh`, once it is enabled you can go to the `Windows Logs -> Security` and find the "Audit Success" entry for that process.

Here is a example of me manually starting `notepad.exe` with it on.

```
A new process has been created.

Creator Subject:
    Security ID:        MyMachine\srchamberlain
    Account Name:       srchamberlain
    Account Domain:     MyMachine
    Logon ID:       0x71FA757

Target Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Process Information:
    New Process ID:     0x1510
    New Process Name:   C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
    Token Elevation Type:   %%1938
    Mandatory Label:        Mandatory Label\Medium Mandatory Level
    Creator Process ID: 0x938
    Creator Process Name:   C:\Windows\explorer.exe
    Process Command Line:
```

The thing we are most interested in is the `Creator Process Name`

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate this advice. Please see the post updated.

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov see my update for the next step.

Comment: You rock, man! I've figured that out finally using your technique with Auditing -- writing the update in the post right now! Appreciate your helping hand!

Comment: You need to follow the chain backward. Find out who started cmd.exe and keep going back till you find the beginning of the chain